# Given a general 3D Matrix operation ... who can I apply "1/2" of the effect of it ?

Tags: matrices

Given a general 3D Matrix operation ... who can I apply "1/2" of the effect of it ?

I have an object with a given orientation in space and a given position ... and another version of same object with a different position and orientation ...

Is there a simple way to find a "middle ground" object that would be "1/2" way between ... say with regard to both position and rotation ? Would be super cool if we had a method that also would work if scale was involved.

I think I can work this all out if I distill out oriented bounding boxes (I have the code and it works for oriented bounding boxed). But ... I was hoping I'm overlooking a cool trick.

Comment: If your matrix is $M$, it sounds like you want the square root of $M$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix .

Comment: Is your transformation necessarily a combination of a translation and a rotation?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that there is a good answer for a general "matrix operation" but there are potential answers for more specific operations corresponding to basic geometric transformations.  If you translate by a vector $\vec{v}$, for example, then 
$$f(\vec{x},t)=(1-t)\vec{x}+t(\vec{x}+\vec{v})$$
yields a point that is between $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{x}+\vec{v}$.  In other words, this yields a partial translation.   As another example, if $R(\theta)$ represents rotation through an angle $\theta$, then $R(t\theta)$ represents a partial rotation for $0<t<1$.

Functions like $f(\vec{x},t)$ are sometimes called [homotopies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy).  I use this type of function in the following answers:

- [Finding a Mobius transformation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1095795/finding-a-m%C3%B6bius-transformation-given-constraints/1095832#1095832)
- [Graph isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393416/are-these-2-graphs-isomorphic/393520#393520)

Answer (score 0):

#### Basic idea

You can linear interpolate from a state $x_1$ to a state $x_2$ via
$$
x_\lambda = (1 -\lambda) x_1 + \lambda x_2 \quad (*)
$$

and $\lambda \in [0, 1]$. If you set $\lambda = 1/2$, you get the state in the middle of the $\lambda$ parameter intervall.

You could try this on the interesting parameters (translation vector, rotation angles) of your transformation matrices.

#### Examples

$$
T_\lambda = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & (1-\lambda)x_1 + \lambda x_2 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & (1-\lambda)y_1 + \lambda y_2 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & (1-\lambda)z_1 + \lambda z_2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$
Here you get translations by $(x_1,y_1,z_1)^T$ to $(x_2,y_2,z_2)^T$.

$$
R_\lambda = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\cos((1-\lambda) \phi_1 + \lambda \phi_2) & \sin((1-\lambda) \phi_1 + \lambda \phi_2) & 0 & 0 \\
-\sin((1-\lambda) \phi_1 + \lambda \phi_2) & \cos((1-\lambda) \phi_1 + \lambda \phi_2) & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

This will rotate from $\phi_1$ to $\phi_2$ in the $x-y$-plane.

$$
S_\lambda = 
\left(
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & (1-\lambda) s_1 + \lambda s_2 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{matrix}
\right)
$$

This will scale the $z$-axis from $s_1$ to $s_2$.

As usual a combined transformation matrix can be calculated by matrix multiplication of the individual transformation matrices.

#### Other transition functions

Of course you can use other transition functions than equation $(*)$.

For visual effects on web pages so called **tweening** libraries became popular in the last years. That term seems to come from "in-between-ing".
Another term used for this is **easing**.

You might find some interesting visual effects for 2D there, which should not be hard to port to a 3D setting. See [here](http://easings.net/en) for such a demo.